# postgresql streaming replication -- continuous archiving?

Tags: postgresql, streaming, replication, archive

im trying to set up streaming replication, but for some reason when i update the database on the master, the changes are not reflected on the standby server UNTIL i restart the postgresql service on the master. (i see new xlog files in master server but these do not get synced to the standby server). when i restart the service on master, i finally see new files added to my shared wal_archive folder

the only way I can make it sync automatically is if i set the archive_timeout.

Master:

```
wal_level = 'hot_standby'   # minimal, archive, hot_standby, or logical
archive_mode = on           # allows archiving to be done
                            # (change requires restart)
archive_command = 'copy "%p" "\\\\VBOXSVR\\wal_archive\\%f"'
max_wal_senders = 3         # max number of walsender processes
                            # (change requires restart)
wal_keep_segments = 10      # in logfile segments, 16MB each; 0 disables
```

pb_hba.conf

```
host    replication  postgres    slaveip/32      trust
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're using archive-based replication without streaming. So it's only replicating when a WAL archive is finished and a new one is opened, which happens:

- When the server does a checkpoint before a clean shutdown
- When a WAL archive is filled by write activity and a new one is needed
- at `archive_timeout` time

If you want continuous replication you need to use streaming replication. See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION) for details. This involves setting a connection string in your downstream server's `recovery.conf` so it can connect directly to the upstream master to receive new writes in near-real-time.

You should still leave archive based replication enabled, because this allows the replica to recover if it's disconnected for a while. It's also useful for point-in-time recovery.